# Adding Git branch to Command Prompt

Tags: windows, git, macos, cmd, iterm

When looking for an alternative for the cool feature in ITerm(mac) which shows the branch we are on:

[image]

I [**found out**](https://gist.github.com/githubteacher/e75edf29d76571f8cc6c) that:

> *If you are on Windows, you probably aren't reading this because Windows provides this behavior by default*.

I had no idea that it is in here by default. How to do it?

Comment: Look at the PS1 environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using git through their console (Git Bash), it is there by default and you don't have to do anything to access it.

[image: Git Bash console]

If you don't have it already, download Git Bash - that's what I'm using in the image above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cmder a console emulator for windows : http://cmder.net/